# kotlin check type incompatible types

Tags: kotlin

I've tried code as below

```
 val a: Int? = 1024
 println(a is Int) // true
 println(a is Int?) // true
 println(a is String) // **error: incompatible types: Long and Int? why the value cannot be checked with any type?**
```

but this works well:

```
fun checkType(x: Any?) {
    when(x) {
        is Int -> ...
        is String -> ... // **It works well here**
        else -> ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works this way:

```
  fun main(args: Array<String>) {
          val a = 123 as Any?  //or val a: Any = 123
            println(a is Int) // true
            println(a is Int?) // true
            println(a is String) //false
      checkType(a) //Int

    }

    fun checkType(x: Any?) {
        when(x) {
            is Int ->  println("Int")
            is String -> println("String")
            else ->  println("other")
        }
     }
```

It's because `val a: Int?` is definetely not one of `String` type, compilator knows it and doesn't allow you to run `a is String`.

You should use more abstract type to define your variable.

Comment: Thx, that's right. Before my questing, I got tow points: 1､ the compiler knows the variable's type at compile phase; 2､ using abstract type can help, as the second example, it works same with val a = 123 as Any?.  So .. I just want to know does Kotlin can check type dynamic like instance in JVM?

Comment: I guess it's better to make your own utility to check class instance and then use it in kotlin. You can write it in java and use in kotlin.... 
Like this, maybe needs some fix:
`fun <T> isType(objectToCast: Any?, implementationInterface: Class<T>): Boolean {
        if (objectToCast == null) {
            return false
        }
        try {
            val castResult: T = implementationInterface.cast(objectToCast)
            return true
        } catch (e: ClassCastException) {
            return false
        }
    }`

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to create a separate function to check its type. You can simply cast to `Any?` type:

```
println(a as Any? is String)
```

Comment: Thanks @Dan Bray.

It's smell like an incomplete intention as the documentation doesn't relate the need to 'abstract' to be able to test : https://kotlinlang.org/docs/typecasts.html#is-and-is-operators

Your solution is very simple and convenient.

Interesting to note that IntelliJ dimmed the 'as Any?' like a redundant / unusefull semantic is this context.